# Why I can't see my cluster details in aws ecs command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I run this command: `aws ecs describe-clusters` which output this result:

```
{                                                                             
    "clusters": [],                                                           
    "failures": [                                                             
        {                                                                     
            "reason": "MISSING",                                              
            "arn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:---------:cluster/default"       
        }                                                                     
    ]                                                                         
}
```

But in https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=us-east-2#/clusters I have a cluster.

[image]

Why I can't see my cluster details in aws ecs command?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't pass the cluster's parameter then it will return the error above

=
for example

```
aws ecs describe-clusters --clusters name-of-the-cluster
```

Comment: still have have the same error message:  `aws ecs describe-clusters --cluster my-cluster`

Comment: I still see you need to pass the service name too --service

Comment: My bad, I thought you need to list services, Im updating my response

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the name of the cluster as well.

e.g.

```
aws ecs describe-clusters --clusters "name-of-your-cluster"

{
    "clusters": [
        {
            "status": "ACTIVE", 
            "statistics": [], 
            "tags": [], 
            "clusterName": "xxxx", 
            "registeredContainerInstancesCount": 1, 
            "pendingTasksCount": 0, 
            "runningTasksCount": 2, 
            "activeServicesCount": 1, 
            "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-south-1:xxxxx"
        }
    ], 
    "failures": []
}
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-clusters.html